# Checkbox is not getting disabled or readonly in table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I'm appending table in html from ajax post in mvc.
I want to make checkbox disable or readonly if condition isActive==true.

```js
//My Ajax Post data call
  $(document).ready(function getDiDControl(pageIndex) {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
         url: ,  //getting Data
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
          /*debugger;*/
          $('#GridRow').empty();
          //$('#pager').empty();
          var trHTML = '';
          var htmlPager = '';
             $.each(data.Controls, function (i, item) {
                        /*debugger;*/
                        trHTML += '<tr>'
                            + '<td  width="{!width}" title=' + '"' + item.ID + '"' + '>' + item.ID + '</td>'
                            + '<td  width="{!width}"title=' + '"' + item.control + '"' + '>' + item.control + '</td>'
                        if (item.isActive == true) {
                            trHTML += '<td> <label class="customcheckbox">'
                                + '<input type="checkbox" onclick="DeactivateControl(' + item.ID ')" class="listCheckbox" checked readonly />'
                                + '<span class="checkmark"></span>'
                                + '</label >'
                                + '</td>'
                        }
                        else {
                            trHTML += '<td> <label class="customcheckbox">'
                                + '<input type="checkbox"  onclick="ActivateControl(' + item.ID ')" class="listCheckbox" />'
                                + '<span class="checkmark"></span>'
                                + '</label >'
                                + '</td>'
                        }
                    });
                    $('#GridRow').append(trHTML)
                    $(tdSelector).attr('title', titleText);
                },
            });
        });
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
           <th scope="col">Control</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody id="GridRow"></tbody>
 </table>
```

I tried everything such as 'disabled', 'readonly' etc. but nothing work.
Created css class with pointer none but it still luck

Comment: First of all but not related to the problem, then you should not have multiple elements with the same id (`chkboxs`). Second are you sure you get into this statement `if (item.isActive == true) {`?

Comment: What do you get when you use `console.log(item.isActive)` ?

Comment: Ids are unique.

Comment: No, Carsten means that you have `'<input type="checkbox" id="chkboxs"` where the id's aren't unique!

Comment: item.isActive is just a condition.  that isActive is my model property

Comment: Ok i will remove that. That id wasn't necessary.

Comment: I know it's a condition, I want to know what your console gives you when you log the value.

Comment: Also depends what  your deactivate control function does

Comment: There is onclick event on both activate and deactive functions.

Comment: I used alert alert(item.isActive) instead console.log(item.isActive) and it gives me true or false.

Comment: you should learn to use `backticks` which would make it way easier to use multiline strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put a +

> in DeactivateControl(' + item.ID +')",

should be like this:

```
trHTML += '<tr>'
                        + '<td  width="{!width}" title=' + '"' + item.ID + '"' + '>' + item.ID + '</td>'
                        + '<td  width="{!width}"title=' + '"' + item.control + '"' + '>' + item.control + '</td>'
                    if (item.isActive == true) {
                        trHTML += '<td> <label class="customcheckbox">'
                            + '<input type="checkbox" id="chkboxs" onclick="DeactivateControl(' + item.ID +')" class="listCheckbox" checked disabled />'
                            + '<span class="checkmark"></span>'
                            + '</label >'
                            + '</td>';
                    }
                    else {
                        trHTML += '<td> <label class="customcheckbox">'
                            + '<input type="checkbox" id="chkboxs" onclick="ActivateControl(' + item.ID +')" class="listCheckbox" />'
                            + '<span class="checkmark"></span>'
                            + '</label >'
                            + '</td>'
                    }
```

And use disabled, readonly not work with checkboxes

Comment: Thank you for the solution. there is + in my code. I made a mistake while pasting. Anyways thank you and have a great day ahead.